# EMF GDI hDC to vector PDF

Tags: pdf, gdi+, gdi

I have a bunch of base emf files that i play on a graphics surface then use gdi to merge text on the surface with drawstring to create a single page report forms. 
The graphics object is then or sent to the printer, or saved as a png and then wrapped in a pdf. (iTextSharp)

I'm looking for a way to keep the pdf  vector based but cant find any open source ways of getting direct access to the dc to be able to draw a metafile image.

My current pdf's are around 800k per page, where if I print the same image to a pdf printer (amyuni) its 23k. The only product that i've found is PdfTron which creates a 200k vector based file directly without printing, but is way too expensive because of all its features.

Do any of graphics experts have any suggestions for an easy way to put metadata directly into a pdf?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: you should remove the emf tag from this Q, because the emf tag on Stack Overflow is re. Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF), whereas your Q relates to Windows Enhanced Metafile (EMF).. ;-)